# How to automatically export different figures with different names in R

Tags: r

I am trying to export different figures with corresponding file names.

For example, there is a table called 'A' and it has following structure.

```
 V1　　　　　　V2 
 chr1　　　　　0.9
 chr1　　　　　0.1
 chr1　　　　　0.2
 chr2　　　　　1.1
 chr2　　　　　1.3
 chr2　　　　　0.1

plot(A[which(A$V1==chr1),2])
plot(A[which(A$V1==chr2),2])
.
.
.
.
```

output files

chr1.pdf
chr2.pdf

I succeeded in making different plots with different titles by V1 column.
However, I cannot make different names of files.

Give me your nice solutions

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to plot by using a MWE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: David, I also want to explain precisely what I want to do. However, I have no idea, how to draw or upload scheme about my situation. I want to make different plot according to V1 column values and then export them into pdf format with names of V1 values

Comment: Have you looked into `ggplot2` and its `ggsave`-function? You are then able to use a `for`-loop to create and save the plot...

Comment: David. Thank you for your suggestion. I will read ggplot2 manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for (v in unique(A$V1)){
  plot(A[which(A$V1) == v, 2])
  dev.copy2pdf(paste0(v, ".pdf"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will take your suggestion.